# Weight matrices computation in attention-based encoder of Deep Learning NLP

Tags: neural-networks, linear-model, deep-learning, linear-algebra, torch

On page 4 of [this research paper](https://www.aclweb.org/anthology/D/D15/D15-1044.pdf) titled `A Neural Attention Model for Sentence Summarization` , it is mentioned the attention-based encoder is determined by the following formula : 
[image]

where dimension of the weight matrices are as follow :
`P` is `H×(CD)`, `F` is `H × V`, `G` is `D × V`.
It is mentioned also in line 2 of the above equations that variable `p` is proportional to `exp(x × P × y)`, which seems to indicate the application of natural exponent and multiplication of the 3 matrices.
With that being said, I have 2 main questions.

1.How can the `x` and `P` in equation of `exp(x × P × y)` perform matrix multiplication with each other, since `x` has the dimension of `1 × (HM)` and `P` has the dimension of `H × (CD)` ? The column of `x` doesn't match the row `P`, so  doesn't that mean matrix multiplication isn't possible? Or is the operations of `x` and `P` not referring to that of a matrix multiplication?

2.I tried checking the source code [here](https://github.com/facebookarchive/NAMAS/blob/a45675e19e24f32133ca8545e9b8267804bfd719/summary/encoder.lua), and I couldn't find the variable that refers to `P` weight variable that is in the article. 
The following are the snippet of the attention-based encoder code :

```
function encoder.build_attnbow_model(opt, data)
   print("Encoder model: BoW + Attention")

   local D2 = opt.bowDim
   local N = opt.window
   local V = #data.title_data.dict.index_to_symbol
   local V2 = #data.article_data.dict.index_to_symbol

   -- Article Embedding.
   local article_lookup = nn.LookupTable(V2, D2)()

   -- Title Embedding.
   local title_lookup = nn.LookupTable(V, D2)()

   -- Size Lookup
   local size_lookup = nn.Identity()()

   -- Ignore size lookup to make NNGraph happy.
   local article_context = nn.SelectTable(1)({article_lookup, size_lookup})

   -- Pool article
   local pad = (opt.attenPool - 1) / 2
   local article_match = article_context

   -- Title context embedding.
   local title_context = nn.View(D2, 1)(
      nn.Linear(N * D2, D2)(nn.View(N * D2)(title_lookup)))

   -- Attention layer. Distribution over article.
   local dot_article_context = nn.MM()({article_match,
                                        title_context})

   -- Compute the attention distribution.
   local non_linearity = nn.SoftMax()
   local attention = non_linearity(nn.Sum(3)(dot_article_context))

   local process_article =
      nn.Sum(2)(nn.SpatialSubSampling(1, 1, opt.attenPool)(
                   nn.SpatialZeroPadding(0, 0, pad, pad)(
                      nn.View(1, -1, D2):setNumInputDims(2)(article_context))))

   -- Apply attention to the subsampled article.
   local mout = nn.Linear(D2, D2)(
      nn.Sum(3)(nn.MM(true, false)(
                   {process_article,
                    nn.View(-1, 1):setNumInputDims(1)(attention)})))

   -- Apply attention
   local encoder_mlp = nn.gModule({article_lookup, size_lookup, title_lookup},
      {mout})

   encoder_mlp:cuda()
   encoder_mlp.lookup = article_lookup.data.module
   encoder_mlp.title_lookup = title_lookup.data.module
   return encoder_mlp
end
```

Based on the snippet above, my guess is that the function :

```
 local dot_article_context = nn.MM()({article_match,
                                        title_context})
```

compute the result of `p` by input of `x`, where `x` is `article match` and `yc` for `title_context`, and there is no involvement of `P` weight matrix at all.
I feel I misunderstood the concept of attention-based encoder computation, and if that's the case, could somebody clarify this up for me in regards to which part of code that actually does the computation of `p`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.If I understood correctly, `x` can be formed as an `M×H` matrix, `P` is `H×(CD)`, `y` is `(CD)×1`, then `exp(x×P×y)` would give a `M×1` matrix, which is used as an unnormalized probability for each word.

2.It seems `dot_article_context` is the result of `x×P×y`, and `attention` (which is obtained by applying softmax to `dot_article_context`) is the probability `p`. My guess is that the code uses the same value `opt.bowDim` for `D` and `H`, and the `P` weight matrix is coded here:

```
-- Title context embedding.
local title_context = nn.View(D2, 1)(
   nn.Linear(N * D2, D2)(nn.View(N * D2)(title_lookup)))
```

in the linear layer `nn.Linear(N * D2, D2)`, so `title_context` should be the result of `P×y`. In this case computing `P×y` first instead of `x×P` is more efficient since `x×P` will give a larger matrix.